# How to generate spatial points with a pattern

Tags: r, random, spatial, points, spatstat

I am doing some work where I need to generate both a) random spatial points b) non-random spatial points, over a polygon i.e. for b) the points probability depends on for example an East-West gradient, or distance from some point source or something else

For a) I can generate random points over a polygon using the `spsample()` command in the `sp` package as follows:

```
# Load a spatial polygon from maptools package
library(maptools)
nc <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],        proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
plot(nc)

library(sp)
pts <- spsample(nc, 100, type="random")
plot(nc)
points(pts, pch=19, col="red")
```

This gives exactly what I want for a). But, can this be modified for b) so points are more likely in the East than the West for example ? (and whilst still being able to specify I want 100 points ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I only know how to do this using the `spatstat` package. With the function `rpoint` You can use any function of the coordinates x,y to define your uneven density of points. Here I define the function to have the value 0 at the West end of the region and grow linearly with slope 100 towards the East:

```
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
nc <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                    proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
nc <- as.owin(nc)
west0 <- nc$xrange[1]
f <- function(x, y, ...){ 100 * (x - west0) }
pts <- rpoint(1000, f, win = nc)
plot(pts)
```

[image: Increasing intensity from West to East]